# How to mock aws-sdk S3 in NestJs

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, nestjs

Faced an issue mocking S3 in nestjs.
I use it for multipart upload.
So the problem is that instead of mocked version of S3, nest still tries to use actual S3, and tries to connect to remote server...

Comment: Share what you have tried so far so we can see how you're attempting to mock the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..Solved this.
The problem was - S3 wasn't a provider for module&service I was testing.
After I added it to providers - I become able to mock it:)
Thanks